# Android Application.mk settings to be able to use c++11 <random> and dynamic_cast

Tags: android, c++11, random, java-native-interface, dynamic-cast

In the Application.mk file, when using APP_STL := stlport_static i can use c++11 dynamic_cast but it won't compile the "random" features.

I've tried APP_STL := gnustl_static and APP_STL := c++_static but those won't let me use dynamic_cast.

What are the Application.mk proper settings to be able to use both at the same time?

My current Application.mk looks like:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11
APP_STL := stlport_static 
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

EDIT:

Following Michaels instructions finally the Application.mk that worked was:

```
#LIBCXX rebuild was needed once when using APP_STL := c++_static
LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_STL := c++_static
#Also the gnu compiler can be used
#APP_STL:= gnustl_static
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
```

Comment: Now open in the AOSP bug tracker: [Issue 216331: STLport does not support C++11](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216331).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you forgot to enable RTTI, which `dynamic_cast` uses to perform run-time type checks.

Quoting from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html):

> [To] ensure compatibility with earlier releases, [the NDK toolchain] compiles all C++ sources with `-fno-rtti` by default.
>
> To enable RTTI support for your entire app for your entire application, add the following line to your Application.mk file:
>
> `APP_CPPFLAGS += -frtti`

I don't see any `random` header among the stlport sources, so it probably doesn't support that feature. Use another STL implementation instead, like gnustl.

So what you need is something like:

```
APP_CPPFLAGS += -std=c++11 -frtti
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Comment: I think that fixed the dynamic_cast usage, but now i'm getting this error: ndk/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/atomic:922: error: undefined reference to '__atomic_fetch_add_4'. and I'm afraid it's not related to the config.

Comment: You need to add `-latomic` to your `LOCAL_LDFLAGS`.

Comment: It works with the gnustl_static but not with the c++_static. Why could this be?

Comment: What doesn't work with c++_static? And for which ABI(s)? And which NDK version and NDK toolchain are you using?

Comment: The -latomic flag is not working: I'm using: ndk-r10e, NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8 and APP_ABI := armeabi right now

Comment: I don't notice any problems. But in any case, that's a separate question and should be posted as such. And if you post that question you should include a minimal complete example (code and makefiles) that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yeah... i solved it if forcing a rebuild: LIBCXX_FORCE_REBUILD := true. Thanks for your help :)